# Можно ли как-то заблокировать размер окна?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

[image: Вот команда]

Вот мне подсказали такую команду, которая изменяет окно, а есть ли какая-то команда, которая установит значение и заблокирует изменение размера данного окна???

```
setfixedHeigth
setfixedWidth
```

не подходят.

---

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> void QWidget::`setFixedSize`(const QSize &s)
>
> Устанавливает как минимальный, так и максимальный размер виджета равным введите сюда код `s`, тем самым предотвращая его дальнейшее увеличение или уменьшение.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedSize

Comment: Если я использую данную команду, то эти размеры сохранятся для всех окон, а нужно для конкретного.. В нужный метод написать - self.FixedSize??

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер  `конкретный_виджет.setFixedSize(300, 400)`

Comment: Добавил выше картинку. Посмотрите ведь это действует на все окна сразу

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер да, `w.setFixedSize(300, 400)` фиксирует размер главного окна. Я же вам писал, что вам надо переопределять размер при отображении нового окна.

Comment: переопределять размер при отображении нового окна, можно в методе, как вы показали, я это понял. Но при переопределении размера, другим окнам дано Право на изменение размера, а это надо как-то убрать. То-есть
1) Изменить размер Нового окна
2)Запретить изменение размера нового окна

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер пожалуйста, подготовьте [mcve] , который демонстрирует проблему. На общий ваш вопрос я вам ответил. The End.

Comment: Так, хорошо, у меня осталось к вам 2 последних вопроса, буду очень признателен если получу ответ.

1) w.setfixedside я установил и после этого, self.resize не в методах не работает

2)через Qt Designer, я установил задний фон в файл (pistoll) , но visual Studio не хочет его воспроизводить, cейчас я кину вам ссылку на гит
cейчас я скину

Comment: https://github.com/Nanoxia123/wednesday18_00
первая папка